# Hash function for varchar ( string) in C++

Tags: c++, integer, hash, varchar

I have a key of varchar(512) type , I want to hash it using the first 2 or first 3 characters of that string only. Please let me know which hash function to use in C++. I want to get hash value in numerics only. The range of number can be of long type i.e. int (64).

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Comment: what are you planning to use the hash for? i.e. what characteristics does it need

Comment: Now that I've gone back through your questions and edited out the signatures, please go back through them and accept their answers!

Comment: @Nercrolis, I have a string key and I would like to map it to numeric, not necessarily unique, i can allow collisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put the characters in an unsigned integer like this:

```
unsigned int hash = ((unsigned int) field[0]) |
                    ((unsigned int) field[1] << 8) |
                    ((unsigned int) field[2] << 16);
```

It's quick, simple, and you get unique values for all unique combinations of the first three letters.

Comment: The only possible problem with this is that if your hashing code picks bits out of the hash, it will get the same value to 8 bits for all strings that have the same first character. One way to fix this is to multiply the hash by a prime close to 2^32/phi such as 2,654,435,761. `hash *= 2654435761U;` will do.

Comment: @JamesKanze Because it does the best job of distributing the input bits evenly over the output bits such that flipping any input bit comes closest to flipping half the output bits. See [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9639/how-did-knuth-derive-a) on cstheory.

Answer (score 0):

Use Boost CRC Hash Function. 
More information here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/crc/index.html

Comment: Thanks Yavar, I am exploring it.